# How to convert columns to rows in unix?

Tags: awk

my input file is:

```
zoo1
----

cat
dog
mouse

zoo2
----

lion
tiger
zebra
```

I want my output file to be:

```
cat,dog,mouse
lion,tiger,zebra
```

Any idea how?

Answer (score 2):

for the example in your question, this one-liner works:

```
 awk -v RS= '/----/{next}{gsub(/\n/,",")}7' file
```

or by setting the `OFS and FS`:

```
awk -v RS= -v OFS="," -F'\n' '/----/{next}$1=$1' file
```

little test:

```
kent$  awk -v RS= '/----/{next}{gsub(/\n/,",")}7' f
cat,dog,mouse
lion,tiger,zebra



kent$  awk -v RS= -v OFS="," -F'\n' '/----/{next}$1=$1' f
cat,dog,mouse
lion,tiger,zebra
```

Comment: What's the significance of the `7`?  Is it just a true value so that records are printed?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes. a non-zero number.

Comment: I know it works; it is great for Code Golf; personally, I don't think a random constant has a place in production code.  I'd prefer to see `{print}` which is explicit.  Although `1` would also do the job, and is semi-conventional, I don't like the (semi-)convention.  I guess I got out of bed on the wrong side this morning.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ awk '!(NR%2){$1=$1;print}' FS='\n' OFS=',' RS= file
cat,dog,mouse
lion,tiger,zebra
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using perl's paragraph mode:

```
$ perl -000 -ne 'next if /---/;print join(",",split(/\n/)),"\n"' file
cat,dog,mouse
lion,tiger,zebra
```

From `man perlrun`:

```
-0[octal/hexadecimal]
     specifies the input record separator ($/) as an octal or hexadecimal number.
     If there are no digits, the null character is the separator.  Other switches
     may precede or follow the digits.  For example, if you have a version of 
     find which can print filenames terminated by the null character, you can say
     this:

            find . -name '*.orig' -print0 | perl -n0e unlink

     The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode.  
     Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by 
     convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose.
```

Answer (score 0):

`tr` provides a very simple and easy to understand way to do this.

`tr -s \\n ","`

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html